# Binary classification with multiple independent outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I'm using this VGG-like model and the input shape is: (num_samples,96,144,3) (96x144 "image" and 3 "channels")

The output shape, instead of being (num_samples,) (which would mean, for each input image there is a binary output: 1 or 0) i have (num_samples, 122). So it means that for each input, i have a vector of outputs (122 outputs where each one could be 1 or 0). I understand that this is a multi-label classification problem, isn't it?

I have a small problem, my data has invalid values (outputs where instead of having 1 or 0 there is a -1, representing that there is no data for that sample in that position of the output vector, which could be just one or more of the 122 positions).
I am masking that values with the masked loss function defined in the code. But i don't know if it is well done.
(source for masked loss: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/pg5Vr-obd_E)

More context of the data in: [ConvNet with missing output data for weather forecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011658/convnet-with-missing-output-data-for-weather-forecast)

```
def masked_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(tf.multiply(y_pred, tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1), tf.float32)),
                                    tf.multiply(y_true, tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1), tf.float32))), axis=-1)

def get_vgg16():
# we initialize the model
model = Sequential()

# Conv Block 1

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 2

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 3
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 4
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 5
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# FC layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(122, activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss=masked_binary_crossentropy, optimizer=sgd, metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy])

return model

model = get_vgg16()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=tam_batch, epochs=cant_epocas, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

The training goes like this:

```
Epoch 1/20 loss: 0.8437 - binary_accuracy: 0.4365 - val_loss: 1.5494 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7706
Epoch 2/20 loss: 0.3512 - binary_accuracy: 0.4386 - val_loss: 1.5494 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7706
Epoch 3/20 loss: 0.3512 - binary_accuracy: 0.4386 - val_loss: 1.5494 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7706
Epoch 4/20 loss: 0.3512 - binary_accuracy: 0.4386 - val_loss: 1.5494 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7706
```

And so on...
What could be the problem? Are the layers in the model the correct approach for this type of problem? Or i should change the last Dense(122,activation='sigmoid') layer???

I have already tried this exact same model but with: a) no invalid data (all samples have a corresponding, valid, 0 or 1); b) the regular, non-masked, binary_crossentropy loss, c) single output (shape = num_samples,1) (i'm just using one of the 122, the one which has zero invalid samples) and d) the last layer Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
And the model works just fine. The final accuracy is more than 90%.

So what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If it has invalid also, then the classes becomes postive (1), negative(0) and invalid(-1).

I assume your data to be in the formal like

```
[features....][0]
[features....][1]
[features....][-1]
```

so do the one hot encoding for the labels so it becomes,

```
[features][1,0,0]
[features][0,1,0]
[features][0,0,1]
```

So prefer using

1. Categorical crossentrophy loss
2. Softmax activation function instead of sigmoid activation function in the final layer.

Comment: Yes but in a same feature can be more than 1 class present, i.e: [features][1, 1, 0, -1, 1...., -1] (the second dimension is 122). So it is a multi-label case

Comment: You can try with a single node output, then this becomes a regression problem predicting 1,0,-1 values which isn't gonna give you any better accuracy. As you needed classification, its better to have single node for each class.